# Issues with parsing huge file

Tags: java, parsing

I'm parsing a document and writing to disk pairs such as these ones:

```
0 vs 1, true
0 vs 2, false
0 vs 3, true
1 vs 2, true
1 vs 3, false
..
```

and so on.

Successively i'm balancing the trues and falses rows for each instance, by removing random lines (lines with true value if they exceed, and viceversa) and I end up with a file such as this one:

```
0 vs 1 true
0 vs 2 false
1 vs 2 true
1 vs 3 true
1 vs 4 false
1 vs 5 false
```

The falses are usually much much more than trues, so in the previous example, I could keep only 1 false for isntance 0, and only 2 falses for instance 1.

I'm doing this process in 2 steps, before parsing and then balancing.

Now, my issue is that the unbalanced file is too big: more than 1GB, and most of its rows are going to be removed by the balancing step.

My question is: can I balance the rows while parsing ?

My guess is no, because I don't know which items are arriving and I can't delete any row until when all rows for a specific instance have been discovered.

I hope it is clear.
thanks

Comment: So, you are reading huge file, then while balancing you are writing another huge file and then you read it again? Am I correct?

Comment: @pajton yeah I'm parsing the first file and building the second file with ALL rows (I'm actually not only parsing, also averaging some items..etc). Successively I'm removing rows from the second file and writing the third one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would happen if you used a lightweight database for this -- derby, h2 etc? I imagine you can write sorting, filtering etc queries to arrive at what you want...

Comment: mhm, you are probably right: databases are dramatically faster than working with java and text files right ?

Comment: Some databases certainly are, but the ones I mentioned write regular old files. The difference lies in how they write the records. The database abstraction also allows you to grow your application without having to completely overhaul a specialized multi-stage file processing algorithm. In essence, I am suggesting that you leave the persistence, caching and query optimization to the database developers, and focus on the actual problem you are solving. With the right isolation level tuning etc, you can reduce database-related overhead, but gain all of their strengths.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only need to load an instance's data at a time, and you only need to record a number and a boolean for each instance value.

I suggest you read the data until the instance number changes (or the end of file is reached)  That should be far less than 1 GB and fix in memory.

If you use TIntArrayList (or an int[]) and BitSet, this will store the data more efficiently. You can clear them after processing each instance.

EDIT: If the data is randomly arranged you may need to read the file once to count the number of true/false for each instance and then read the file again to produce the result.

Another option is try to load the whole file into memory a different way.  You should be able to load 1 GB of data in this format and get it to use less than 1 GB.

You need to loow at how you can minimise the overhead you get for each row of data and you can reduce consumption significantly.

```
class Row { // uses a total of 80 bytes in a 32-bit JVM
    // 16 byte header
    Integer x; // 4 + 24 bytes.
    Integer y; // 4 + 24 bytes.
    Boolean b; // 1 byte
    // 7 bytes of padding.
}

class Row { // uses a total of 32 bytes in a 32-bit JVM
    // 16 byte header
    int x; // 4  bytes.
    int y; // 4 bytes.
    boolean b; // 1 byte
    // 7 bytes of padding.
}

class Rows { // uses a total of 8-9 bytes/row
    // 16 byte header
    int[] x; // 4 bytes/row, TIntArrayList is easier to use.
    int[] y; // 4 bytes/row
    BitSet b; // 1 bit/row
    // 7 bytes of padding.
}

// if your numbers are between -32,768 and 32,767
class Rows { // uses a total of 4-5 bytes/row
    // 16 byte header
    short[] x; // 4 bytes/row, TShortArrayList is easier to use.
    short[] y; // 4 bytes/row
    BitSet b; // 1 bit/row
    // 7 bytes of padding.
}
```

Comment: @Peter Lawrey yeah exactly the data is randomly arranged, the other option would be to count the number of trues and falses for each instance. But I'm afraid it is a bad solution, I should scan all file for each group of instances and I have many small groups.

Comment: I think I should work with databases instead, Java and text files are too slow for it.. what do you think ?

Comment: You should be able to read/write 1 GB in about 10-20 seconds.  I don't believe you will be able to load 1 Gb of data from a database much faster.

Comment: "the other option would be to count the number of trues and falses for each instance" I wouldn't have suggested it if I thought it was a bad option.

Comment: Also, successively the best thing to do is probably to sort the rows by group so they are not anymore randomly arranged and I can balance them on fly.

Comment: Your limitation is the speed you load the data from disk. If you want this even faster, I suggest improving your disk hardware or keeping the file in memory at all times (either in the OS disk cache or the application memory)

Comment: If you can get the data pre-sorted it could be twice as fast. If you have to sort the data as a first step, this will add more time than it will save. In that case you are better off taking it as it comes.

Comment: One way to speed up the processing is to shorten the data format e.g. `1 2 T` will read faster than `1 vs 2 true` possibly half the size of the file. Or even `1T2` and `3F7`

Comment: BTW: I think the biggest block you have is that 1 GB is huge, therefor processing it has to be complicated.  I regularly process 20 GB of text data, I do it all in memory and I try to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I think I will import it into mysql, in that way I should sort by group faster. Successively I balance on fly and keep working with mysql...

Comment: About the file format it is actually a xml file... so it is not minimal at all. I guess importing it into a database solves the issue...

Comment: If its in XML, you should have no trouble loading it into memory as long as you don't use an XML document model.  This is because it will be much larger on disk than in memory.  Sorting it in memory will be trivial.  I suggest you use a SAX parser to turn each row into a data value as it is processed. My application reads about 20 GB of XML per day this way.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Mhm, I'm using Commons Digester as parser, I'm now planning to sort it with java and then count the positive instances for each group and write them to disk, successively write the same number of negative instances.

Comment: I don't know how this behaves for large files. Do you get OOM errors? SAX parses each row individually and won't use any more memory than the longest piece of text between tags (or the longest tag) This is generally much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas -

1) If the file is 1GB, you may be able to load it into a data structure, but you've probably already tried this
2) If the data is sorted or grouped by row, you can read each line until you hit a new row and rebalance
3) If the data isn't sorted you could sort the file in-place with a random access IO class and then do 2)
4) If that's not possible, you could always make several passes over the file for each row, this will obviously be slow.

Comment: I think as first thing I should import the text file into mysql as dataset. I guess this would dramatically improve the performances. Secondly, I need to sort it by group indeed, and this is probably something to do with mysql queries rather than java programming. Than I can balance on fly as you say.